# Pros and Cons of being an editor for an edited book volume

Tags: editors, books, early-career, call-for-papers

I am early in my tenure track position. I have just completed my post-doc and PhD two years ago. In collaboration with colleagues, we have recently circulated call-for-papers for an edited book.

What are the potential pros and cons of being a co-editor of an edited book given my career stage?

The propsed edited volume is broadly based on social science and related disciplines.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could state your field. It is really dependent on the area.

Comment: This can't be answered without specifying a discipline.  Also, ask your chair.

Comment: I personally dealt with this (TT, US, Engineering). In my case, the chair and TPR committee were supportive (but they both stressed how grants + papers should have priority). Major con: it was a bit hard to convince "big names" in my field to agree to contribute with a chapter (given that I was a junior faculty). Major pro: my dept. was happy for me for landing a contract from a well "respected publisher" very early into my TT journey.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth. Mainly, the edited book is based on social science and other related disciplines, for example, management, health policy etc.

Comment: @user3571389 -- your best resource is going to be your colleagues. They will eventually have to decide about your tenure and can tell you what they value in your dossier.